# Validate the textbox for length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Title" onkeyup="CheckLength(this.value);"/>
```

and in JavaScript file ,

```
function CheckLength(currentValue)
{
   if(currentValue.length > 6)
      alert("Only 6 letters are allowed, please follow the rule!");
}
```

what I want is after 6 characters, whatever user will type should not visible in the Text-box and should show an alert..Can you help me in this?

Comment: Do you want a jQuery solution ? An angularjs solution ? A native javascript solution ?

Comment: i want native js or angular js

Answer (score 5):

There is something called  **[maxlength](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)** attribute.

> The maxlength attribute specifies the maximum number of characters allowed in the  element.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Title" maxlength="6"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function CheckLength(currentValue)
{
   if(currentValue.length > 5)
   return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="return CheckLength(this.value);"/>
```

Also you can add attribute maxlength to input element to restrict the number of character like

```
<input type="text" maxlength="6"/>
```